# In my layout there is recyclerview and bottom navigation bar but navigation bar goes behinf the recycler view

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio, android-recyclerview

In my layout there is recyclerview and bottom navigation bar but the problem is that the recyclerview occupies all the view and the bottom navigation bar and the header bad goes behind the recycler view. I've sucessfully implemented the material dependency.

this is the layout:

[image: this is the layout]

This is the code of the layout.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--status bar-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/default_activity_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:menu="@menu/default_menu" />

    <!--add button-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="6.2sp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="15sp"
        app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="#ED4444"
        android:onClick="openCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"

        app:maxImageSize="35sp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_list" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_list"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_icon"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_no_data" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Scan the files"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scan to make something great"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by giving specific height to the BottomAppBar. Then provide margin top and Bottom to the RelativeLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--status bar-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/default_activity_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:menu="@menu/default_menu" />

    <!--add button-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/buttoncolor"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="6.2sp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="15sp"
        app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="#ED4444"
        android:onClick="openCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"

        app:maxImageSize="35sp"
        app:tint="@color/white" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rw"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_list" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_list"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_icon"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_no_data" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Scan the files"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_list_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scan to make something great"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:paddingRight="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```